# Как правильно протестировать сервис-слой, использующий репозиторий?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, юнит-тесты, mockito

В моем сервис-слое есть метод, использующий репозиторий, в котором находится запрос к БД. 
Мне потребовалось протестировать данный сервис, не используя SpringRunner (нужно не создавать реального соединения с БД в тестах, т.к. используется несколько профилей и тесты должны быть независимы от профиля). 
Было решено использовать **Mockito**, где я и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

**Тест метода**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)

public class DBLogReaderTest {

private static final Long LOG_ID = 1L;
private static final String JAVA_ID = "1ID";
private static final String MESSAGE = "message";

private static ModelMapper mapper;

@InjectMocks
private DBLogReader logReader;

@Mock
private RestLogRepository restLogRepository;

@Mock
private RestLogRepositoryCustomImpl restLogRepositoryCustom;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mapper = new ModelMapper();
    logReader = new DBLogReader(mapper);
}

@Test
public void contextLoad() {
    assertThat(logReader).isNotNull();
}

@Test
public void readLogs() {
    RestLogDto log = new RestLogDto();
    log.setId(LOG_ID);

    List<RestLogDto> logList = new ArrayList<>();
    logList.add(log);

    when(restLogRepositoryCustom.getAllJoinedRecords(
        any(PageRequest.class), any(Date.class), any(Date.class))
    ).thenReturn(logList);

    assertEquals(logReader.readLogs(0, 10, ZonedDateTime.now().minusHours(23), ZonedDateTime.now()), logList);
}
```

Мокнув `restLogRepositoryCustom.getAllJoinedRecords()` я был уверен, что логика, реализованная внутри самого сервиса, вернет мне результат, описанный мной в блоке when(). Однако вместо этого я ловлю **NullPointerException**.

Стектрейс ошибки:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ru.logsmanager.service.DBLogReader.readById(DBLogReader.java:62)
at ru.logsmanager.service.DBLogReaderTest.readById(DBLogReaderTest.java:78)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

**Сервис:**

```
@Autowired
RestLogRepositoryCustomImpl restLogRepositoryCustom;

public List<RestLogDto> readLogs(Integer page, Integer size, ZonedDateTime userFromDate, ZonedDateTime userToDate) {
    ZonedDateTime toDate = Optional
        .ofNullable(userToDate)
        .orElseGet(() -> Optional
            .ofNullable(userFromDate)
            .orElseGet(ZonedDateTime::now)
            .plusDays(1)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .minusNanos(1));

    ZonedDateTime fromDate = Optional
        .ofNullable(userFromDate)
        .filter(date -> ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(date, toDate) < 24)
        .orElseGet(() -> Optional
            .ofNullable(userToDate)
            .orElseGet(ZonedDateTime::now)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .minusDays(1));

    return restLogRepositoryCustom.getAllJoinedRecords(
        PageRequestUtils.of(
            page, size, PageRequestUtils.pageOf(), PageRequestUtils.sizeOf(5, 200)),
        Date.from(fromDate.toInstant()),
        Date.from(toDate.toInstant()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, проблема была в этом куске кода:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    mapper = new ModelMapper();
    logReader = new DBLogReader(mapper);
}
```

Аннотация `@InjectMocks` сама создает экземпляр класса, куда и вставляет уже созданые Mock'и. Таким образом строчка с созданием нового экземпляра класса - лишняя. Правильный вариант:

```
@InjectMocks
private DBLogReader logReader;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mapper = new ModelMapper();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не могу точно сказать, почему Ваш способ не сработал, но насколько мне известно, сервисы не должны работать с конкретной реализацией репозиториев, а всё их взаимодействие и в принципе взаимодействие между слоями должно осуществляться через интерфейсы.

Потому наилучший и самый правильный вариант тестирования в данном случае - изменить тип `restLogRepositoryCustom` с конкретной реализации на какой-нибудь интерфейс `RestLogRepository`, а в тестах написать реализацию этого интерфейса, которая просто возвращает нужные Вам данные, не обращаясь к БД.

Например, вот так это может выглядеть в тесте:

```
public void setup() {
    mapper = new ModelMapper();
    logReader = new DBLogReader(mapper);

    logReader.restLogRepositoryCustom = new RestLogRepository {
        public List<RestLogDto> getAllJoinedRecords() {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    };
}
```

Я могу ошибаться, так как я не знаю всей картины, и возможно у Вас этот подход может вызвать проблемы, но я думаю, основную мысль о том, в каком направлении стоит думать, Вы уловите.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, я учту это на будущее, но не думаю что это является решением проблемы того, что метод  getAllJoinedRecords() внутри вызываемого readLogs() возвращает не то, что нужно.

Comment: Понимаю, но с тестами и моком не знаком, так что написал, что знаю